# e.clientX is undefined error in console but still works

Tags: javascript

For some  reason the console keeps on saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
    at moveCircle (script.js:5) but the code still works in the browser. Could you explain how that error is appearing in the console?

```
1  const CIRCLE = document.querySelector(".circle");
2  const BODY = document.body;
3  
4  function moveCircle(e) {
5      CIRCLE.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
6      CIRCLE.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
7  }
8  
9  BODY.addEventListener("mousemove", moveCircle, false);
10 setInterval(moveCircle, 1);
```

Comment: When you comment out the setInterval line the error should go away.

Comment: Because `e` variable in `moveCircle` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Function `moveCircle` called by `setInterval` doesn't have event object.

Function `moveCircle` triggered by event `mousemove` will work.

Why do you want call `moveCircle` by `setInterval`?

Comment: Oh yeah I guess the setInterval doesn't make sense thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of things please use window requestAnimationFrame (rAF), since rAF or setTimeout cannot access event directly, your best choice is to either record the event somewhere and consume it from there, or store the last coordinates and operate on them. Something like this maybe??

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/8z5a5sgj/5/

```
var circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
var pos = [0,0];
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mousemove",updatePos,false);
window.requestAnimationFrame(move);


function updatePos(e){
    pos[0] = e.clientX || 0;
  pos[1] = e.clientY || 0
}
function move(){
    var diffX = pos[0] - circle.offsetLeft;
  var diffY = pos[1] - circle.offsetTop;
  if(diffX) {
    circle.style.left = circle.offsetLeft+Math.max(-5,Math.min(diffX/10,5))+"px";
  }
  if(diffY) {
    circle.style.top = circle.offsetTop+Math.max(-5,Math.min(diffY/10,5))+"px";
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that requestAnimationFrame() existed.